# How to tell if something is scrolled into view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to re-create something similar to the effect [here](http://www.edmsauce.com/2013/09/02/modern-dealer-releases-new-ep-edm-sauce-exclusive/). When you scroll down to the bottom of the page, an "Also Check Out" div slides from the right. I am assuming this works by using the jQuery function `scroll` and then checks if a certain div is in view or not. I, however, cannot even get the `scroll` function to work. I tried both using `$("#div_name").scroll(function(){});` and `$("#div_name").on("scroll", function(){});`, but neither seem to be working. It appears that neither one of my ways of going about it are hooking the scroll functions properly. Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GmbBu/)

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong in my fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

As has been posted multiple times here:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'waypoint'` in my console... link: http://jsfiddle.net/GmbBu/1/

Comment: Oh I see it's an external jquery library, not a native one?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get something like this
Edited **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/GmbBu/3/)**

Script:

```
$(function(){
        var a;var c=false;
        var b=$("#popContent");
        var e=$(window);
        var d=$('#footer').position().top;
        e.scroll(function(){
            window.clearTimeout(a);
            a=window.setTimeout(function(){
            if(e.scrollTop()<=d){
              if(c==false)   { 
                  c=true;b.stop(true,true).show(); 
                  }else{
                         c=false;b.fadeOut(500)

            }}},100)})
});
```